Why does React put TextField values into query params on submit?
This is not helpful as it doesn't work
Why does React put textfield values in the queryparams? I'm making a Login page and for some reason React just puts user's credentials into URL when they click the Login button ? (on submit form)
The values are correct when I print/alert them from the onChange functions but why do they end up in queryparams? preventDefault did nothing

import * as React from 'react';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import logo from '../img/logo.png'
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { tryLogIn } from '../utils/mockServices/login';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"



const Login = () =>{
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const [login,setLogin] = React.useState([])
    const [pass, setPass] = React.useState([])

    const defaultTheme = createTheme();

    const handlePassChanged = (e) => {
        setPass(e.target.value)
    }

    const handleLoginChanged = (e) =>{
        setLogin(e.target.value)
    }

    const handleLogin = async () => {
        const response = await(tryLogIn(login,pass))
        alert(response)
        if(response){
            navigate("/main")
        }
        else{
            alert('bad')
        }
    }

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
          <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
            <CssBaseline />
            <Box
              sx={{
                marginTop: 8,
                display: 'flex',
                flexDirection: 'column',
                alignItems: 'center',
              }}
            >
            <Avatar sx={{ m: 1, bgcolor: 'secondary.main',width: 80, height: 80 }}>
            <img
                      alt=""
                      src= {logo}
                      width="90"
                      height="90"
                      className="d-inline-block align-top"
                    />
            </Avatar>
              <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                login page
              </Typography>
              <Box component="form" noValidate sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
                <TextField
                  margin="normal"
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  id="login"
                  label="Login"
                  name="login"
                  autoComplete="login"
                  autoFocus
                  onChange={handleLoginChanged}
                />
                <TextField
                  margin="normal"
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  name="password"
                  label="Password"
                  type="password"
                  id="password"
                  autoComplete="current-password"
                  onChange={handlePassChanged}
                />
                <Button
                  type="submit"
                  fullWidth
                  variant="contained"
                  sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
                  onClick={handleLogin}
                >
                  Log in
                </Button>
              </Box>
            </Box>
          </Container>
        </ThemeProvider>
      );
}

export default Login;


Having the value stored in query params on form submission is the default behaviour of the browser because it's typically sending the form action to the server. You can decide to stop this by adding event.preventDefault to your handleLogin function and passing the onSubmit event handler to the Box component that is being used as a form in your code. I have made an update to your code below and I hope it solves it for you.
import * as React from 'react';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import logo from '../img/logo.png'
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { tryLogIn } from '../utils/mockServices/login';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"

const Login = () =>{
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const defaultTheme = createTheme();

    const [loginCredentials, setLoginCredentials] = useState({ login: "", password: "" })

    const onChangeHandler = (event) => {
      setLoginCredentials(prev => ({...prev, [event.target.name]: event.target.value}))
    }

    const handleLogin = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const response = await(tryLogIn(login,pass))
        alert(response)
        if(response){
            navigate("/main")
        }
        else{
            alert('bad')
        }
    }

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
          <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
            <CssBaseline />
            <Box
              sx={{
                marginTop: 8,
                display: 'flex',
                flexDirection: 'column',
                alignItems: 'center',
              }}
            >
            <Avatar sx={{ m: 1, bgcolor: 'secondary.main',width: 80, height: 80 }}>
            <img
                      alt=""
                      src= {logo}
                      width="90"
                      height="90"
                      className="d-inline-block align-top"
                    />
            </Avatar>
              <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                login page
              </Typography>
              <Box component="form" noValidate sx={{ mt: 1 }} onSubmit={handleLogin}>
                <TextField
                  margin="normal"
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  id="login"
                  label="Login"
                  name="login"
                  value={loginCredentials.login}
                  autoComplete="login"
                  autoFocus
                  onChange={onChangeHandler}
                />
                <TextField
                  margin="normal"
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  name="password"
                  label="Password"
                  type="password"
                  id="password"
                  value={loginCredentials.password}
                  autoComplete="current-password"
                  onChange={onChangeHandler}
                />
                <Button
                  type="submit"
                  fullWidth
                  variant="contained"
                  sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
                >
                  Log in
                </Button>
              </Box>
            </Box>
          </Container>
        </ThemeProvider>
      );
}

export default Login;

I have also refactored some aspects of your code. It's redundant to have different useState setter functions for the login and the password TextFields and also managing them with two different state change handler functions.

thanks for responding and your help! but as i mentioned in my original post the similar question on this website didn't help me as "preventDefault" did nothing for me. The correct solution is to remove Login button's "submit" type and just handle the onClick event normally
